# Saving pdf on server side with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, java, html, primefaces, jspdf

I have an application that generates a HTML page with data which the user can edit. 
At the end I generate a .pdf file with jsPDF.
Is there any way that I can save this generated .pdf on my server-side database?

I'm using PrimeFaces.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is not javascript, not java-se, not html, nor PrimeFaces related. And where do you generate the pdf? Client Side? Can you store it in an input element? Then this question boils down to getting the value of an input element to the server. Please break down your problem to what it actually boils down to. Now it is way to broad and unclear

Comment: Do you mean that you want to upload your file in some repository to save it ?!? it's true that it's a little bit unclear.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, yes, I generate the pdf on client side. The point is that in this HTML sheet the user is able to type texts and change some datas fetched by the application on the database.
I want to save the .pdf generated by the jsPDF library.

Comment: This may help you it also work for me. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786132/how-to-save-pdf-file-from-jspdf-on-a-server-in-javascript/51787493#:~:text=save%20function%20you%20have%20to,SERVER%5B'DOCUMENT_ROOT'%5D%20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating my solution for other users:

I found the `.output('datauristring')` method of the jsPDF which returns me a BASE64 String.

Then the String is sent via JSON to my backed bean and converted as my will.

Comment: See, if you break down the problem it boils down to what you found out. Asking a question in that direction would have been way easier like: How can I get the output of jsPDF in a string?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for the help! I've found my solution:

Once the user presses on the button to generate the .pdf, I'll save all the data he filled on the database, just the data.

When the user wants to see the pdf he generated back, I'll generate a new one with the data collected on his first submit.

Thank you all for the answers, they were helpful.

Comment: This is not an 'answer' to the problem. You solved it in a totally different way. But keep in mind, that if the PDF is needed for some kind of 'proof', this 'workaround' may not be the right solution!

Comment: I know it is not the right solution, Kukeltje, but my deadline is coming and I have to move forward.
Workarounds always come to a problem eventually, but I have to skip it for a while.
Thank you for concern Mr. Kukeltje, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

It is a open source cross platform command line tool to generate pdf files from html content.

So to your requirement what you can do is, you need to send the html content to the server and save this content into a html file.

Once you saved html content into html you can call wkhtmltopdf like you execute MS-DOS commands in java.

**Example:** `new ProcessBuilder("wkhtmltopdf.exe", htmlFilePath, pdfFilePath);`

Once pdf file is generated  you can read and store into database.

Comment: User is already using jspdf... And if doing java and you want to suggest something different, I would suggest https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject Much better integration

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kukeltje and Mr. Ravi MCA