# How to save PDF file from jsPDF on a server in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jspdf

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
$('#generatereport').click(function() {
   doc.fromHTML($('#lppresults')[0], 15, 15, {
   width: 170
   }, function() {
   doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<div class="survey-results" id="lppresults">
    <button id="generatereport">Download Report</button>
    <h1 style="border: solid;">TEST CONTENT</h1><br />
    <h1 style="border: solid;">TEST CONTENT1</h1>
</div>
```

I want to save file on the server with JavaScript, but currently I can save this file only on the user's computer.

Comment: Which server, is it `node`, `IIS`?

Comment: IIS I Thing But Code Run In Php

Comment: So do you want to store it on IIS Server?

Comment: I am using php so server is linux

Comment: Then you need to create one API which will accept the `PDF` file and saved on your WebServer

Comment: @DilipShekhawat, after 15 points of reputation you can give your vote for an answer. If you like my answer you could upvote it.  **please read:** [What should you do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of `doc.save` function you have to use [`doc.output`](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#output) function with type `'blob'` as a parameter.

In Javascript part:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
$('#generatereport').click(function()
{
    doc.fromHTML(
        $('#lppresults'), 15, 15,
        {width: 170},
        function()
        {
            var blob = doc.output('blob');

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('pdf', blob);

            $.ajax('/upload.php',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){console.log(data)},
                error: function(data){console.log(data)}
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Here is the code for `upload.php`:

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/test.pdf"
);
?>
```

Comment: Great its too helpful and work for me thank you save my hours

Comment: Really useful, thank you. I wish the difference between .save and .output would have been clearer in the documentation and easier to find.