# Save PDF File created by jsPDF on FTP

Tags: html5-canvas, jspdf

I have the following problem:
I've created a simple JS function that creates a PDF from a canvas. I can only download this file with the `doc.save('file.pdf')` function. How can I save it in a folder on my FTP server?

```
function salvapdf() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); 
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * 210 / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;

      var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
      var position = 0;

      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, 210, imgHeight);
      heightLeft -= 295;

      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        doc.addPage();
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, 210, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= 295;
      }
      doc.save('file.pdf');
}
```

/NAMEfolder

> page.html
>   NEWFILECREATED.pdf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51787493/1181367