# How to save PDF file from jsPDF on a server in Javascript with its real name in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, controller, jspdf

it is my javascript code :

```
 var input = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0].name; 
         var file = doc.output('blob');
           var formData = new FormData();
           formData.append('file', file);
           $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
                            });
        $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url:'/saveEditorFiles',
                data: {formData,name:input},
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){console.log(data)},
                error: function(data){console.log(data)}
                });
            
            
            and its controller : 

       

  public function storeEditorFiles(Request $request)
            {
                $validatedData = $request->validate([
                    'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf',
                ]);
                $file = $request->name('file');
                $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $uniqueName = bin2hex(random_bytes(3)) . '.' .'pdf';
                $file->move(public_path('TempFiles/'), $uniqueName);
                $save = new TempFile;
                $save->filename = $name;
                $save->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $save->UniqueFileName = $uniqueName;
                $save->save();
                $response = [
                    'name' => $name,
                    'file' => $file,
                ];
                return Response::json(['success' => $response]);
            }
```

the problem is that the file is saving in my database with the name "blob". I am trying to save it with its original name. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can any body help me with this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save PDF file from jsPDF on a server in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786132/how-to-save-pdf-file-from-jspdf-on-a-server-in-javascript)

Comment: I used it already but it didn't save my file with its real name.

Comment: Can you show your imports. Where is TempFile coming from?

Comment: I used file reader to show my pdf in pdf container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found an a soloution append child and in second parameter pass the targeted var name:

```
var realName= document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0].name; 
 var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', file);
          **formData.append('name','realName');** // realName is targeted file name
 $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
                            });
        $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url:'/saveEditorFiles',
                data: {formData,name:input},
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){console.log(data)},
                error: function(data){console.log(data)}
                });
```

and in controller :

```
 public function storeEditorFiles(Request $request)
            {
                $validatedData = $request->validate([
                    'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf',
                ]);
                $file = $request->name('file');
                $file = $request->name('realName');
                $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $uniqueName = bin2hex(random_bytes(3)) . '.' 
                .'pdf';
                $file->move(public_path('TempFiles/'), 
                 $uniqueName);
                $save = new TempFile;
                $save->filename = $name;
                $save->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $save->UniqueFileName = $uniqueName;
                $save->save();
                $response = [
                    'name' => $name,
                    'file' => $file,
                ];
                return Response::json(['success' => $response]);
            }
```